# How to update total with selected radio

Tags: jquery, html, sum

I'm still working on auto total form with input, radio and dropdown. Input and dropdown works very well. But the radio is not as it should be. The form is sum the radio values even it's not selected. I only need the form to auto-sum only when a radio is clicked. Here's my code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var $total = $('#total'),
    $value = $('.value');
  $value.on('input input[type=radio]:checked', function (e) {
    var total = 0;
    $value.each(function (index, elem) {
      if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(this.value, 10)))
        total = total + parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });
    $total.val(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="5" id="value1" name="value1" class="value" />Value 1
<br />
<input type="radio" id="value5" name="value2" class="value" value="5"/><label for="value5">+ 5</label>
<br />
<input type="radio" id="value10" name="value2" class="value" value="10"/>
<label for="value10">+ 10</label>
<br />
Value 4
<select name="value4" id="value4" class="value">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<hr />
Total
<input type="text" size="5" id="total" readonly="readonly" class="bckground" name="total" />
```

[Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6GV/50/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the current item is a radio and make sure it is checked using [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), else you can skip the current iteration by `return`, as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var $value = $('.value');
  $value.on('input', function (e) {
    var total = 0;
    $value.each(function (index, elem) {
        if ($(elem).is("input[type='radio']") && (!$(elem).is(":checked")))
           return;
        if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(this.value, 10)))
           total = total + parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });
    $('#total').val(total);
  });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6GV/51/)

*Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6GV/55/)*

Comment: @Wilf because it doesn't have an `input` event. Your code runs when `input` event occurs. If you want it to update on clicking radio, use both `input` and `change` instead [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6GV/55/)

Comment: This is exactly answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only events like `'keyup keypress blur change input'` can only pass to on function. You should handle change event for textbox and dropdrop and handle click event for checkbox.

```
$('.value').on('change click', handleEvent);
```

You shouldn't loop through all elements that has class `.value` because it include unchecked checkbox.

```
function handleEvent() {
    $('.value').each(function(i, ele){
        if ($(ele).is("input[type='radio']") && (!$(ele).is(":checked"))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!Number.isNaN(parseInt(ele.value))) {
           total += parseInt(ele.value);
       }
    }
}
```